# Displaying picture on microcontroller's screen

Tags: c, image, microcontroller

Hi I am trying to let my picture (that has a size of: 40 x 42)  take more space that’s available on my microcontroller, because as you can see my face is pretty small on the screen:

[image]

The first thing that I had tried, was to use a bigger picture with a size of 70 x  73. But then it puts the picture in the same place in with no room left to fit in:

[image]

The problem is also that  I need to create more space/room, because I want to put a bigger picture of myself on the screen. But I don’t know how I can fix this can someone please help me, please?

This is the code that I use to display my tiny picture (40 x 42) on the microcontroller:

```
showCredits() {

while (1) {
    // 38 width, 44 height
    //int asciiZaky [44] [38]
   // int asciiZaky [42] [20] = { //40 x 42 size
   // int asciiZaky [73] [35] = { //70 x 73 size
    int asciiZaky [44] [38] = { //40 x 42 size
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,},
{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,}
    };


    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= 128; i++) {
        drawScreen(dogmScreen, 8, 128);
        for (j = 0; j <= 64; j++) {
            setPixel(i, j);
            if (45 <= i && i < 83 && //Aligning the image to the center
                    10 <= j && j < 54 && // Putting the image below
                    asciiZaky [j - 10] [i - 45] == 1// Giving good values to the array
                    ||
                    (i > 108 && j > 52) // Right under corner
                    ) {
                clearPixel(i, j);
            }
        }

    }   
  }
}
```

And here are some other attempts, but I have not yet succeeded:

[image]

[image]

Comment: your `if` statement limits you to a rectangle of 38px in width and 44px in height. So here is your problem. It would be waaaaay more clear if you had a buffer containing the 0/1 to display on ALL the screen. Clear it to 0 to begin, then define a function that "add" your picture inside this matrix. They in your double for loop, just read this matrix, if it's a 1 call setPixel(). (FYI, even on the first picture, 2 pixels are missing on the right (38 pixel display, 40px picture))

Comment: Simply use Run-length encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify the code, it's not easy to read. 
Define these two functions somewhere above:

```
void clearScreen(int color) {
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<=128;i++) { //Did you really mean 129 wide? If not, remove the '='
        for(j=0;j<=64;j++) {
            if(color) setPixel(i,j);
            else clearPixel(i,j);
        }
    }

void bitblt(int x, int y, int sx, int sy, int *pic) {
    int i,j;

    for(i=x;i<sx;i++) {
        for(j=y;j<sy;j++) {
            if(pic[i][j]) setPixel(i,j);
            else clearPixel(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your while loop:

```
while(1) {
    clearScreen(1); //You seem to clear to black
    bitblt(34,0,60,64,zaky); //60x64 is the largest for the given aspect
}
```